# isnan in numpy array with mixed datatype does not work

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I use pandas to parse an excel sheet, which contains an unbalanced panel. So in some columns there are empty cells, which are parsed as `NaN`. Then I want to obtain unique values of the panel data without the `NaN` entry. However, `np.isnan` fails due to fact that the entries are strings and the nan entry a float. Is there a nice way out?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xls = pd.ExcelFile('File.xls')
data = xls.parse('Sheet1', index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
uniqueID  = pd.unique(data.values.ravel())
uniqueID[~np.isnan(uniqueID)]
```

Comment: does `pd.notnull()` or `data.dropna()` work?

Comment: `pd.notnull()` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having access to your data, for pandas at least there is the top level `isnull` and also this is available for the [`df`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html#pandas.DataFrame.notnull) or [`series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html#pandas.Series.notnull), you can also call [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas.DataFrame.dropna):

```
In [3]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asdsa', np.NaN, 98]})
df
Out[3]:
       a
0  asdsa
1    NaN
2     98
In [13]:

pd.notnull(df)
Out[13]:
       a
0   True
1  False
2   True
```

We can call `notnull()` on the series to filter the rows:

```
In [14]:

df[df['a'].notnull()]
Out[14]:
       a
0  asdsa
2     98
```

or we can just call `dropna` on the df:

```
In [15]:

df.dropna()
Out[15]:
       a
0  asdsa
2     98
```

Comment: The data frame looks like this: `df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['asdsa', np.NaN, 98],'b':[np.NaN, np.NaN, 99] })`. I then want a unique vector of all elements, excluding `NaN`. In this case, 'asdsa', 99, 98. If I simply replace `np.isnan(uniqueID)` by `pd.notnull(uniqueID)` in the code of the question it works. The problem with `df.dropna()` in that case is that it drops all rows including `NaN`s.

Comment: `dropna` is for dropping entire rows or columns if nan's exist or if a threshold is not meant, `pd.notnull` is a top-level function that just filters the entire df of any nan values when used as a mask